# GWT/GXT adding nocache.js file, in the header or after the body?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I notice that most GXT/GWT applications put the nocache.js file after the body tag.  And few seem to put in the include in the header tag.  Why is that?

Comment: Good question... I remind reading a book where it was recommended to include JS files at the end, but not everybody agrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that the GWT script tag will be evaluated synchronously (the tag), but fetched *asynchronously* (the code, into an iframe), I don't see why not put it as the very first thing. Time saved!

Unless, you have some kind of complex logic that cannot have the chance to be properly displayed before the `onModuleLoad()` call (e.g., images evaluated but still not fetched), much like Steffen Schäfer pointed out. But you can defer you app startup for them though.

For more info, have a look [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideBootstrap).

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view there are 2 cases:

1. If you use GWT to only enhance your page that is generated on the server side then put the `<script>` at the end. That allows your browser to render the initial content of the page before parsing the JS code.
2. If you built a single page application that is completely generated by GWT on the client side, there's no content to be initially shown. In that case you can put the `<script>` to the head.

Be aware that 1. also applies if you implemented a loading animation or placeholder content to be initially shown.